# Code which works on my VS code does not work in Code wars - Moving Zeros To The End task?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, visual-studio-code, python-3.10

Was having fun with this task on code wars where on a given list as an input my function should find all of the zeroes and put them at the end of a given list maintaining the other numbers in the same order for example:
a = [1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1] function should return a = [1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]

I wrote a code which in my VS code does the job but for some reason cant pass the initial tests (4/5).

The thing is on failed test where my function should return some values, IT ACTUALLY DOES, in my compiler but cant pass test??? I'm really confused. I did not want to look for solutions online...

Here is my code:

```py
def zerotoanend(a:list):
    b = []
    for i in a:
        if i==0:
            b.append(0)
            a.remove(i)
    for zero in b:
        a.append(zero)
    return a
```

Comment: Can you share the *failed* test here? We cannot see what's happening on that one - unless you share more info.

Answer (score -1):

It is generally not a good idea to modify a `list` while iterating over it, as you can skip elements. Instead, you could count the number of zeros first, use a list comprehension to get all the non-zero elements, then add the required number of zeros to the end.

```py
zeros = a.count(0)
return [x for x in a if x != 0] + [0] * zeros
```

Comment: Thank you! Well, initially it was my core idea, to count and separate all the zeros in b list and then that number or total zeros add at the end of 'a' list.